# What is the maximum area of a square inserted within a region limited by certain functions?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry, functions, analytic-geometry

What maximum area of a square inserted within a region limited by certain functions?

The problem is relatively easy when we calculate the maximum area of a square inserted within a region defined, for example, by a parabola $f(x)$ and the x-axis, as shown in the graph below:
[image]

In this case the limited region is defined by all $R(x, y)$ such that $y \geqslant 0$ and $y \leqslant f(x)$, with $f(x) = p(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$ and $p \lt 0$.

$A_{max}$ is maximum when also $a$ is maximum: $A_{max} = a^2_{max}$.

But the problem here is more complex: How to determine the maximum area of a square inserted in a region limited by 3 functions (curves or straight lines)? The graph below illustrates an example of a region limited by functions $f, g, h$:
[image]

Suposing that $f(x) = -2x + 20$, $g(x) = x^2 - 10x + 30$, and $h(x) = -\frac{x^2}{5} + 4x$, and all $P(x,y)$ belongs to Region defined by:

- $y \geqslant f(x)$
- $y \geqslant g(x)$
- $y \leqslant h(x)$

Note that the vertices of the square do not necessarily have to belong to the curves!

Determine a method for finding $A_{max}$.

This link is a spectacular video that didactically shows a similar problem. It appears to be an unresolved topology problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8

See also the link for a similar problem that asks what the largest number of squares with defined sides can be compacted in a given region:
[What is the maximum number of squares we can compact within a defined area?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540212/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-squares-we-can-compact-within-a-defined-area)

Comment: I think your example is simpler than the general case, as $h(x)=35-g(x)$, so there's a symmetry in the two parabolas. I'd recommend first drawing an accurate graph of the three functions.

Comment: Well remembered Gerry Myerson! I corrected that in the statement. In fact it makes it a little more generic, although this is just an example. thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking about how to attack this difficult problem. One idea would be to work with the diagonals of the square that are perpendicular. The diagonal maxims would give us the maximum square. But both diagonals could not exceed the limits given by the functions! Note that we could also divide the region into parts (where the curves intersect) and analyze the families (bundles) of maximum possible diagonals! it's just an idea, I don't know if that would help!

Comment: The [Inscribed Square Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem) is yet to be solved. Hence we do not even know if there even is a square for every combination of three functions.

Comment: Great link Sam! This really is a very difficult problem! according to Wikipedia: The inscribed square problem, also known as the square peg problem or the Toeplitz' conjecture, is an unsolved question in geometry: Does every plane simple closed curve contain all four vertices of some square? This is true if the curve is convex or piecewise smooth and in other special cases. The problem was proposed by Otto Toeplitz in 1911.

Comment: See also the link with a spectacular video that didactically shows the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8